# Add new user and role to asp.net identity sample?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I have installed asp.net identity sample https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples and trying to create a new role "SAdmin" with the user "Sadmin@example.com". The user is created but "Sadmin" gets the same role as "Admin"

I have modified IdentityConfig.cs to

```
    //Create User=Admin@Admin.com with password=Admin@123456 in the Admin role        
    public static void InitializeIdentityForEF(ApplicationDbContext db) {
        var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var roleManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        const string name = "admin@example.com";
        const string password = "Admin@123456";
        const string roleName = "Admin";

        const string Sname = "Sadmin@example.com";
        const string Spassword = "SAdmin@123456";
        const string SroleName = "SAdmin";

        //Create Super if it does not exist
        var Srole = roleManager.FindByName(SroleName);
        if (Srole == null)
        {
            Srole = new IdentityRole(roleName);
            var roleresult = roleManager.Create(Srole);
        }

        var Suser = userManager.FindByName(Sname);
        if (Suser == null)
        {
            Suser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Sname, Email = Sname };
            var result = userManager.Create(Suser, Spassword);
            result = userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(Suser.Id, false);
        }

        // Add Suser to Role Admin if not already added
        var SrolesForUser = userManager.GetRoles(Suser.Id);
        if (!SrolesForUser.Contains(Srole.Name))
        {
            var result = userManager.AddToRole(Suser.Id, Srole.Name);
        }

        //Create Role Admin if it does not exist
        var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName);
        if (role == null) {
            role = new IdentityRole(roleName);
            var roleresult = roleManager.Create(role);
        }

        var user = userManager.FindByName(name);
        if (user == null) {
            user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = name, Email = name };
            var result = userManager.Create(user, password);
            result = userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, false);
        }

        // Add user admin to Role Admin if not already added
        var rolesForUser = userManager.GetRoles(user.Id);
        if (!rolesForUser.Contains(role.Name)) {
            var result = userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, role.Name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean gets the same role? you can check the db content and see which roles each user has.

Comment: The user "Sname" is added to the role "Admin", not the role "SAdmin" when I look in the DB.

Comment: Can you check your roles table and make sure there are 2 roles defined?

Comment: I only have one role ("Admin") in AspNetRoles. What is wrong?

Comment: Try to debug it, cause you add the `SAdmin` first, make sure that it is added and that they are not overwritten one another..

Comment: Forgot "S" in var Srole = roleManager.FindByName(SroleName); Thanks!

Comment: Add role list in database and use it. Or check roll is null or emty in if condition at page load. If it's empty or null then assign unique roll to that user

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the code... The following code block is responsible

```
    if (Srole == null)
    {
    **Srole = new IdentityRole(roleName);**
    var roleresult = roleManager.Create(Srole);
    }
```

Change the highlighted line to

```
    **Srole = new IdentityRole(SroleName);**
```

That should solve it